# Cmake C++ Visual Studio 2019 project with wxWidgets as a sub directory

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxWidgets in a C++ Cmake project in Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio I did this:
New project -> C++ -> Cmake project (Build modern, cross-platform C++ apps that dont depend on .sln or .vcxproj files).

[image]

Now I ran the project and got the "Hello CMake." message.

In the documentation (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmake.html) it states that you can add wxWidgets:

```
# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory(libs/wxWidgets)
add_executable(myapp QuickImageForensicsCmake.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp net core base)
add_subdirectory ("QuickImageForensicsCmake")
```

Now I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     CMake Error at
>   C:\Users\user\source\repos\QuickImageForensicsCmake\CMakeLists.txt:9
>   (add_subdirectory):   add_subdirectory given source "libs/wxWidgets"
>   which is not an existing
>   directory.    QuickImageForensicsCmake    C:\Users\user\source\repos\QuickImageForensicsCmake\CMakeLists.txt  9

I have added the wxWidgets folder under a folder named libs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image of your project layout, it looks like have an *additional* `QuickImageForensicsCmake` directory nested in root of your project hierarchy. Try the following instead to get to the CMakeLists.txt file in `QuickImageForensicsCmake/libs/wxWidgets`:

```
add_subdirectory(QuickImageForensicsCmake/libs/wxWidgets)
```